# Animate.css and Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with playing the animation if audio is paused.  I only want the animation to work when I play the audio.  When I pause the audio, I don't want any animation.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/n7xqz3d0/1/

```js
$(function(){

var audiocircle= $("#audio")[0]; //audio variable


$('.box').click(function(){


 if (audiocircle.paused){
audiocircle.play();
animationClick('.box','jello');

function animationClick(element, animation){
  element = $(element);
  element.click(
    function() {
      element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
      //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
      window.setTimeout( function(){
element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
      }, 2000);
    }
  );
};

}  else {

       audiocircle.pause();
}
});

});
```

```css
.box{
  background:green;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="box">
  <audio id="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"></audio>
  <p>
  Jesus What
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [created a JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/o5tc2jm8/2/). I've updated the `var` from `status` to `mstatus` because I think it created a conflict.

Code:

```js
  var mstatus = 1;
$('.control').on('click',function(){
  var e = document.getElementById("audio");
  if(mstatus === 1){
   e.play();
    $('.control').addClass('animated shake');
    mstatus = 2;
  }else{
    e.pause();
    $('.control').removeClass('animated shake');
    mstatus = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
.control{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
<audio id="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Please place essential parts of the answer here rather than using a link. I've submitted an edit to fix that for you, please accept it.

Comment: @cybermonkey the code are running in snippet? because i try to preview, and nothing show, i am confuse,

Comment: [The code in the snippet works fine...](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11679809).

Comment: @cybermonkey ok, i cant see anything, ^_^ thats why i put in fiddle.

Comment: Works fine my end, ensure that you aren't blocking anything from Stack Exchange.